# Can we use cfset inside cfquery?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Can we use **`<cfset>`** tag inside **`<cfquery>`** tag?  And how to pass listqualify result to **`<cfqueryparam>`** ?
Below is my code :

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE _id in (#listqualify(idList,"'")#
```

Here idList is supplied by another data source. I want to use  on above code to make sure that input is properly provided. 
I have tried below code but not sure whether i am going on right way or not.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE _id in (<cfset idList=#listqualify(idList,"'")#><cfqueryparam value="#idList">)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Tushar showed you how to do this with CF.  However, if you can do this at the database level, do so.  It depends on the database engine and permissions.

Comment: By the way, what happened when you ran that code?

Comment: I bet you got an error saying something like "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ''123','456','789'' to data type int.", right?

Comment: Yes Sebastian. You are right. It is giving an error as you said.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can use `<cfset>` tag inside another tag like below:

```
<cffunction ....>
<cfset x = 'a'>
</cffunction>
OR
    <cfquery ...>
      <cfset x ='a'>
    </cfquery>
```

The way you are doing is not aesthetically pleasing, you can do it as follows:

```
<cfset idList = listQualify(idList,"'")>
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE _id in 
(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#idList#" list="yes">)
```

Comment: Thanks . can you please check my question again ? i have updated it

Comment: Thanks Tushar for your help.

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary to use the listqualify() function at all.  The list attribute of cfqueryparam takes care of that.

Comment: What is the difference between using listqualify() and list attribute  ? I know that listqualify would take delimiter as second parameter and add it at the beginning and end of the list and return as string.

Comment: Your description of ListQualify() is inaccurate.  Your google search string is `coldfusion listqualify`.  Also, acknowledge the possibility that Tushar guessed the datatype correctly.

Comment: To be clear, `listQualify()` is even wrong in this case, because if your IDs are integers, they will be interpreted as strings, and if they are strings, the quotes will be interpreted as parts of the values. And you must use the `list` attribute of `<cfqueryparam>` instead in order to get proper results, otherwise your parameter holding the list will be interpreted as one big string.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sebastian. I have tested the above code with listQualify() but it was giving an error. It is working with list attribute

Comment: It is giving an error when i using this statement `<cfset idList = listQualify(idList,"'")>`. As you said If the IDs are integers, it will be interpreted as strings and for the strings, the quotes are parts of the values. In  this case using listQualify() totally irrelevant